How to apply rate limit in magento open source 2.4.7
I have applied all the settings as per defined in Adobe dev docs https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/webapi/get-started/rate-limiting/ but it is not working for me. If anyone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

can you specify what is not working and how are you testing that the rate limit is not been applied?

did you check the logs to see if appears the entries metioned here

yes, I have checked the logs but no logs are recorded in the log files.
